# CMake - How to stop building every dependency every time I build my project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake

I have a cmake list file that is pulling in dependencies via `ExternalProject_Add`. On initial compilation of my project (which uses these dependencies) I would expect them to be built (or if the configuration changes say from Debug to Release). This occurs, however it occurs after any subsequent code change in the project source. So for example if I simply add a line to `cout` something to the terminal and build my project, visual studio goes through every project that is associated with my project and rebuilds it. Granted it skips actually re-compiling when not necessary, but going through the whole build step for each dependency is not ideal.

Therefore I'm wondering how I might structure this cmake project to avoid each dependency having to be built every time I make a change in my project's source?

Below is my `CMakeLists.txt` file. It's a work in progress. I'm simply adding pieces and testing as I go to insure I'm receiving the results I want (also some non cross platform things in here that are done simply for testing purposes at the moment):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20.0)


# Define our project name
set(PROJECT_NAME test)
project(${PROJECT_NAME})

if(MSVC)
    get_filename_component(_vs_bin_path "${CMAKE_LINKER}" DIRECTORY)
    set(libexe "${_vs_bin_path}/lib.exe")
    message("LOOKHERE3:${libexe}")
endif()

# Make sure binary directory is not the same as source directory
if(PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR STREQUAL PROJECT_BINARY_DIR)
  message(
    FATAL_ERROR
      "In-source builds not allowed. Please make a new directory (called a build directory) and run CMake from there."
  )
endif()


# This Project Depends on External Project(s) 
include(ExternalProject)

# SETUP GLFW
set(libGLFW glfw)
ExternalProject_Add(${libGLFW}
PREFIX          ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/dep/${libGLFW}
GIT_REPOSITORY  https://github.com/glfw/glfw.git
GIT_TAG         3.3.4
GIT_SHALLOW     ON
CMAKE_ARGS      -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/dep/${libGLFW}/install
                -DGLFW_BUILD_DOCS:BOOL=OFF
                -DGLFW_BUILD_EXAMPLES:BOOL=OFF
                -DGLFW_BUILD_TESTS:BOOL=OFF
)

set(GLFW_INSTALL_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/dep/${libGLFW}/install)
add_library(GLFW_LIBRARY STATIC IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(GLFW_LIBRARY PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${GLFW_INSTALL_DIR}/lib/${CMAKE_STATIC_LIBRARY_PREFIX}glfw3${CMAKE_STATIC_LIBRARY_SUFFIX})
#message("LOOKHERE:${CMAKE_STATIC_LIBRARY_PREFIX}glfw3${CMAKE_STATIC_LIBRARY_SUFFIX}")


# SETUP GLAD
set(libGLAD glad)
ExternalProject_Add(${libGLAD}
PREFIX          ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/dep/${libGLAD}
GIT_REPOSITORY  https://github.com/Dav1dde/glad.git
GIT_TAG         origin/master
GIT_SHALLOW     ON
CMAKE_ARGS      -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/dep/${libGLAD}/install
                -DGLAD_INSTALL:BOOL=ON
                -DGLAD_PROFILE:STRING="core"
                -DGLAD_ALL_EXTENSIONS:BOOL=ON
                -DUSE_MSVC_RUNTIME_LIBRARY_DLL:BOOL=OFF
)

set(GLAD_INSTALL_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/dep/${libGLAD}/install)
add_library(GLAD_LIBRARY STATIC IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(GLAD_LIBRARY PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${GLAD_INSTALL_DIR}/lib/${CMAKE_STATIC_LIBRARY_PREFIX}glad${CMAKE_STATIC_LIBRARY_SUFFIX})




# CREATE OUR LIBRARY
file(GLOB_RECURSE headers CONFIGURE_DEPENDS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/inc/*.h")
file(GLOB_RECURSE sources CONFIGURE_DEPENDS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/*.cpp")

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} STATIC ${headers} ${sources})
add_dependencies(${PROJECT_NAME} ${libGLFW} ${libGLAD})


# Add all include file paths
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME}
    PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/inc
    PUBLIC ${GLFW_INSTALL_DIR}/include
    PUBLIC ${GLAD_INSTALL_DIR}/include
)


# JOIN ALL LIBS
set(LIBNAME "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/final/combinedLib.lib")

add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT ${LIBNAME}
    COMMAND ${libexe} /OUT:${LIBNAME} $<TARGET_FILE:GLFW_LIBRARY> $<TARGET_FILE:GLAD_LIBRARY> $<TARGET_FILE:${PROJECT_NAME}>
    DEPENDS GLFW_LIBRARY GLAD_LIBRARY ${PROJECT_NAME}
    COMMENT "Combining libs..."
)

add_custom_target(combinedLibGenerator
    DEPENDS ${LIBNAME}
)

add_library(combinedLib STATIC IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET combinedLib PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION ${LIBNAME})
add_dependencies(combinedLib combinedLibGenerator)
```

And this is the output I'm receiving in visual studio after every build:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: ZERO_CHECK, Configuration: Release x64 ------
2>------ Build started: Project: glad, Configuration: Release x64 ------
2>Performing update step for 'glad'
2>HEAD is now at 71b2aa6... readme: updates conan link
2>No patch step for 'glad'
2>Performing configure step for 'glad'
2>-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.16299.0 to target Windows 10.0.18362.
2>-- Configuring done
2>-- Generating done
2>-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/myuserid/Desktop/test/build/dep/glad/src/glad-build
2>Performing build step for 'glad'
2>Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.5.180.51428 for .NET Framework
2>Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
2>
2>  glad.vcxproj -> C:\Users\myuserid\Desktop\test\build\dep\glad\src\glad-build\Release\glad.lib
2>Performing install step for 'glad'
2>Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.5.180.51428 for .NET Framework
2>Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
2>
2>  glad.vcxproj -> C:\Users\myuserid\Desktop\test\build\dep\glad\src\glad-build\Release\glad.lib
2>  -- Install configuration: "Release"
2>  -- Up-to-date: C:/Users/myuserid/Desktop/test/build/dep/glad/install/lib/glad.lib
2>  -- Up-to-date: C:/Users/myuserid/Desktop/test/build/dep/glad/install/include/glad/glad.h
2>  -- Up-to-date: C:/Users/myuserid/Desktop/test/build/dep/glad/install/include/KHR/khrplatform.h
2>  -- Up-to-date: C:/Users/myuserid/Desktop/test/build/dep/glad/install/lib/cmake/glad/gladConfig.cmake
2>  -- Up-to-date: C:/Users/myuserid/Desktop/test/build/dep/glad/install/lib/cmake/glad/gladConfigVersion.cmake
2>  -- Up-to-date: C:/Users/myuserid/Desktop/test/build/dep/glad/install/lib/cmake/glad/gladTargets.cmake
2>  -- Up-to-date: C:/Users/myuserid/Desktop/test/build/dep/glad/install/lib/cmake/glad/gladTargets-release.cmake
2>Completed 'glad'
3>------ Build started: Project: glfw, Configuration: Release x64 ------
3>Performing update step for 'glfw'
3>No patch step for 'glfw'
3>Performing configure step for 'glfw'
3>-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.16299.0 to target Windows 10.0.18362.
3>-- Using Win32 for window creation
3>-- Configuring done
3>-- Generating done
3>-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/myuserid/Desktop/test/build/dep/glfw/src/glfw-build
3>Performing build step for 'glfw'
3>Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.5.180.51428 for .NET Framework
3>Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
3>
3>  glfw.vcxproj -> C:\Users\myuserid\Desktop\test\build\dep\glfw\src\glfw-build\src\Release\glfw3.lib
3>Performing install step for 'glfw'
3>Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.5.180.51428 for .NET Framework
3>Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
3>
3>  glfw.vcxproj -> C:\Users\myuserid\Desktop\test\build\dep\glfw\src\glfw-build\src\Release\glfw3.lib
3>  -- Install configuration: "Release"
3>  -- Up-to-date: C:/Users/myuserid/Desktop/test/build/dep/glfw/install/include/GLFW
3>  -- Up-to-date: C:/Users/myuserid/Desktop/test/build/dep/glfw/install/include/GLFW/glfw3.h
3>  -- Up-to-date: C:/Users/myuserid/Desktop/test/build/dep/glfw/install/include/GLFW/glfw3native.h
3>  -- Up-to-date: C:/Users/myuserid/Desktop/test/build/dep/glfw/install/lib/cmake/glfw3/glfw3Config.cmake
3>  -- Up-to-date: C:/Users/myuserid/Desktop/test/build/dep/glfw/install/lib/cmake/glfw3/glfw3ConfigVersion.cmake
3>  -- Up-to-date: C:/Users/myuserid/Desktop/test/build/dep/glfw/install/lib/cmake/glfw3/glfw3Targets.cmake
3>  -- Up-to-date: C:/Users/myuserid/Desktop/test/build/dep/glfw/install/lib/cmake/glfw3/glfw3Targets-release.cmake
3>  -- Up-to-date: C:/Users/myuserid/Desktop/test/build/dep/glfw/install/lib/pkgconfig/glfw3.pc
3>  -- Up-to-date: C:/Users/myuserid/Desktop/test/build/dep/glfw/install/lib/glfw3.lib
3>Completed 'glfw'
4>------ Build started: Project: test, Configuration: Release x64 ------
4>Test.cpp
4>test.vcxproj -> C:\Users\myuserid\Desktop\test\build\Release\test.lib
========== Build: 4 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: This is performed by msbuild of MS Visual Studio, not by cmake. Unload the projects that you don't want to attempt to be built.

Comment: @S.M. Are you saying to simply remove the projects from the solution once they've been built? What if the build configuration changes from say Debug to Release and a rebuild would actually be required? Or would you just pre-build for each configuration and then remove the projects...that seems kind of obtuse. Or am I not picking up what you're putting down?

Comment: Remove those `add_dependenices` and replace them with proper `target_link_libraries`.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot That indeed does the trick! However upon the initial `ALL_BUILD` the build fails stating it cannot find include files for the dependent projects. Is there a way that I can set the build order without using `add_dependencies`?

Comment: In a typical CMake project, you only manage dependencies using `find_package(glfw3 REQUIRED)` then you do `target_link_libraries(my-exe PUBLIC glfw)` Linking to the target will add the linking and the headers and the defines.

Comment: The find package will either search for an installed distribution of glfw (that can be in a local directory in your project tree) or use a `Findglfw.cmake` in your project, in which you can put the ExternalProject_Add things there.

Comment: Simply doing the target link libraries with properly defined targets will take care of it. You only need `add_dependencies` when you use custom targets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding `UPDATE_COMMAND ""` to `ExternalProject_Add` achieves the behavior I was after. This keeps the build system from walking through each dependency and checking it for changes every time something that depends on it is built. Switching configurations (ie Debug/Release) triggers the rebuild as expected. Then if you ever need to rebuild, you would just rebuild the specific dependency.

```
# SETUP GLFW
set(libGLFW glfw)
ExternalProject_Add(${libGLFW}
PREFIX          ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/dep/${libGLFW}
GIT_REPOSITORY  https://github.com/glfw/glfw.git
GIT_TAG         3.3.4
GIT_SHALLOW     ON
CMAKE_ARGS      -
# BEGIN ADD THIS
UPDATE_COMMAND  ""
# END ADD THIS
DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/dep/${libGLFW}/install
                -DGLFW_BUILD_DOCS:BOOL=OFF
                -DGLFW_BUILD_EXAMPLES:BOOL=OFF
                -DGLFW_BUILD_TESTS:BOOL=OFF
)
```

Comment: Thank you!!! I was stuck on this for over an hour.

Answer (score 0):

There's a bug in CMake that results in ExternalProject_Add with GIT_TAG always rebuilding, as it doesn't know if the git update has changed anything. See:

https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/16419
https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/19703

As in whitwhoa's answer, using UPDATE_COMMAND may workaround this.